# C Language Single char declaration error after char array

Tags: arrays, c, char, c-strings, atoi

There seems to be an overflow phenomenon depending on the declaration of ***n*** before and the declaration of ***n*** after Can you tell me the detailed reason?

Operable code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, sum=0;
    char n, DNA[11]={};

    printf("용의자의 DNA정보를 입력하세요. :");
    scanf("%s", DNA);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        n = DNA[i];
        sum += atoi(&n);
    }

    if (sum%7 == 4)
        printf("범인");
    else
        printf("일반인");
}
```

Inoperable code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, sum=0;
    char DNA[11]={}, n;

    printf("용의자의 DNA정보를 입력하세요. :");
    scanf("%s", DNA);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        n = DNA[i];
        sum += atoi(&n);
    }

    if (sum%7 == 4)
        printf("범인");
    else
        printf("일반인");
```

*Input conditions are up to 10 characters

Comment: If you give more than 10 characters as input for `DNA` then you will have problem. Use the format `%10s` to limit the possible input.

Comment: Input conditions are up to 10 characters
Thank you for your reply. I'll explain it in more detail next time

Answer (score 2):

The both programs have undefined behavior.

For starters you may not use empty braces to initialize an array in C (opposite to C++).

```
char n, DNA[11]={};
```

Secondly, the function `atoi` expects a pointer to a string. However you are using a single character `n`

```
sum += atoi(&n);
```

If you want for example to add digits of the entered number then write

```
for(i=0; DNA[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    n = DNA[i];
    sum += n - '0';
}
```

Also you need guarantee that the length of the entered string is not greater than 10

```
scanf("%10s", DNA);
```

Comment: Could you tell me in detail why we can't initialize the array in C using empty brackets at first?

Comment: @계정테스트 By the C grammar definition.